# mesos ps giving error

Tags: python, mesos

On a `CentOS` server where we have configured `mesos 0.28.2`, I am getting error when running `"mesos ps"`

mesos ps

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/bin/mesos-ps", line 10, in
>   from mesos import http
>   ImportError: cannot import name http

Tried setting `PYTHONPATH` to be `"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"` but still not helping.

`Python` version is 2.7.5
Saw [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3149) , but not getting exactly what action is required.

Answer (score 0):

pip install mesos.cli

See here: https://reviews.apache.org/r/45209/